# .animate() doesn't work in IE10 but works in IE9, IE8, IE7, Chrome, and FF

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer-10

On this website, when you mouse over the boxes, a div slides in from the left. For some reason, it works on every modern browser except IE10. On IE10, nothing happens when you mouse over the boxes. The code for this is below. I included the surrounding code in case there is something in there that is causing this. Also, nothing shows up in the console for IE10 which is making it frustrating to debug this. If someone can take a look and see where I went wrong, it would be a huge help to me.

```
  $(function () {
    var time_effect = 400;
    var effect_name = 'easeOutQuart';

    // Hovers
    var hovers = function () {
      $('.project-mask').hover(function () {
          $('.description', this).stop().animate({
            left: 0
          }, 50);
       }, function () {
          $('.description', this).stop().animate({
            left: -280
          }, 50);
       });
       $("a.single-image").fancybox({
         transitionIn: 'none',
         transitionOut: 'none',
         overlayColor: '#000',
         overlayOpacity: 0.6
       });
    };

    //Extracted quicksand block
    var applyQuicksand = function (selector, quicksandArgs) {
      $('.all').quicksand(selector, quicksandArgs);
      $('.filter a').removeClass('selected');
    };

    var objArgs = {
      quicksandFunction: applyQuicksand,
      quicksandArgs: {
        duration: time_effect,
        attribute: 'data-id',
        easing: effect_name,
        adjustHeight: 'auto',
        useScaling: false,
        enhancement: hovers
      }
    };

    //Call hovers for initial load
    $('.all').quicksand($('.everything article'), objArgs.quicksandArgs);

    $('.filter-all').click(objArgs, function (e) {
      objArgs.quicksandFunction($('.everything article'), objArgs.quicksandArgs);
      $(this).addClass('selected');
      e.preventDefault();
    });

    $('.filter-web').click(objArgs, function (e) {
      objArgs.quicksandFunction($('.web article'), objArgs.quicksandArgs);
      $(this).addClass('selected');
      e.preventDefault();
    });

    $('.filter-print').click(objArgs, function (e) {
      objArgs.quicksandFunction($('.print article'), objArgs.quicksandArgs);
      $(this).addClass('selected');
      e.preventDefault();
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: This should be done in CSS anyway, not jQuery. A simple `:hover` class with the appropriate `transition` property can achieve the exact same effect much more efficiently.

Comment: @Kolink Thank you, I will consider going that route.

Comment: @Kolink if you need to support IE7/8/9 as well, then css transitions will not do. In that case you'll have to fall back on Javascript (jQuery) anyway.

Comment: @RenéWolferink It's eye-candy. IE7 and up all support the use of `:hover`, so they'll show the panel but without the sliding motion.

Comment: Yes, `:hover` has been supported for a while now. But if your client also wants the eye-candy to be shown for people who are still running IE9 (or lower), a warning that css transition effects don't work in older IE versions should definitely be given.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with QuickSand. It has issues with IE10

You should try and get the latest version for [QuickSand](https://github.com/razorjack/quicksand) from GitHub

Comment: Thank you, I just figured it out. But I will give you the check.